# Is a function of velocity a function of time?

Tags: functions, physics, mathematical-physics

Let $U:\mathbb{R}^6\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function which variable dependence is
$$
U(x,y,z,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z}),
$$
where $x,y,z\equiv x(t),y(t),z(t)$ and $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$. Is it correct to simplify the previous dependence to a function $U:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}$, such that
$$
U\equiv U(x,y,z,t)?
$$
My goal is to show that a function depending on the velocity is a function depending on time. Is this true?

**Edit:** This is related to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529126/a-proof-that-air-resistance-isnt-conservative), where $U$ is the potential energy associated with a non-conservative force. My goal is to simplify the following expression
$$
\frac{d}{d t}U (x,y,z,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z}).
$$
Any ideas?

Comment: In the Hamiltonian or the Lagrangian formulation of classical dynamics (and later many other "dynamics"), the partial derivatives with respect to $\dot x$ etc (and friends) are explicitly used.

Comment: In the case of non-conservative forces which depend on the velocity (like drag or air resistance), can I simply say that they depend on time to show that energy is dissipated? It would make the proof a lot easier..

Comment: If you're using this for Lagrangian or Hamiltonian mechanics (or similar), then you really need to keep the dotted variables. The machinery you're going to use in that case depends on things like $\frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot x}$, the partial derivative of $U$ with respect to _its fourth variable_ $\dot x$ (regardless of what physical relationship that fourth variable happens to have to the first variable $x$).

Comment: I see. I guess in my case I want to simplify something like $\frac{d}{d t}U (x,y,z,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})$. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand why people are talking about Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics when neither this answer nor the related one mentions that. OP's is asking if it is possible to use the depence of the variables $\dot x,\dot y$ and $\dot z$ on $t$ to simplify the expression of $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write $U:\mathbb{R}^6\to\mathbb{R}$ we are saying that every point $P$ in the $\mathbb{R}^6$ (or, at least, in some sub-domain of $\mathbb{R}^6$) is mapped to a value $U(P) \in \mathbb{R}$. There is no suggestion of a trajectory or flow of time here. The fact that we may interpret some of the co-ordinates in $\mathbb{R}^6$ as a position vector and others as a velocity vector is irrelevant.

If we now define a curve $Q(\lambda)$ in $\mathbb{R}^6$ as a sequence of points $Q: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^6$ then we have an implicit function $V: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $V(\lambda) = U(Q(\lambda))$. If we now identify the parameter $\lambda$ with time and say that

$Q(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t), \dot x (t), \dot y (t), \dot z (t)) \\
V(t) = U(x(t), y(t), z(t), \dot x (t), \dot y (t), \dot z (t))$

then we have

$\frac {dV}{dt} = \frac {\partial U}{\partial x} \frac {dx}{dt} + \dots + \frac {\partial U}{\partial \dot z} \frac {d \dot z}{dt}$

By a conventional but somewhat confusing abuse of notation, we often write $\frac {dU}{dt}$ instead of $\frac{dV}{dt}$, glossing over the fact that the function $U: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ in $\frac {dU}{dt}$ is not the same as the function $U: \mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Great, now I get it. Is there a way of simplifying $\frac{dV}{dt}$? For example, in the case where I only have $x,y,z$-dependence and letting $r=(x,y,z)$, I could write $\frac{dV}{dt}=\nabla U \cdot \dot{r}$. Any idea how to compress it when including $\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z}$ using $\ddot{r}$, for instance?

Comment: As commented in @Willy.K's answer, if I could "hide" the dependence on $\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z}$ in the time variable $t$, $U(x,y,z,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})\equiv U(x,y,z,t)$, then I could simply use $\frac{dV}{dt}=\nabla U\cdot \dot{r}+ \frac{\partial U}{\partial t}$, where $\nabla$ here is the spatial gradient (over $x,y,z$) and $r=(x,y,z)$. But this doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: @sam I think you may be confusing yourself by using $U$ to mean several different things. Is $U$ a function on $\mathbb{R}^6$, on $\mathbb{R}^4$ or on $\mathbb{R}^3$ ? Starting with $U(x,y,z,\dot x, \dot y, \dot z)$ how *exactly* do you define your $U(x,y,z,t)$ ?

Comment: What if I write $\tilde{U}(x,y,z,t)=U(x,y,z,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})$?

Comment: @samwolfe Suppose $U(x,y,z,\dot x, \dot y, \dot z) = \dot x$. What is your $\tilde U (x,y,z,t)$ ?

Comment: $\tilde{U}(x,y,z,t)=\frac{dx}{dt}\equiv \dot{x}$

Comment: @samwolfe But $\dot x$ is not a function of $x,y,z,t$. Remember there is *no* trajectory in $\mathbb{R}^6$ or in $\mathbb{R}^4$ at this stage. Once you specify a trajectory parameterised by time then $U$ is implicitly a function of $t$ alone and you don't need $\tilde U(x,y,z,t)$.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand it now. Maybe I'd have to define $\tilde{U}$ as an operator? I think there's not much more I can say.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between writting $U(x,y,z,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})$ and $U(x,y,z,t)$. When you write $U(x,y,z,t)$ you mean that there is a possible *explicit* dependence on $t$, while in $U(x,y,z,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})$ this dependence is *implicit*. This will make a difference in the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian formalism since, for the first case, the partial derivative $\partial U(x,y,z,t)/\partial t$ can be evaluated and is not usually zero but in the second case $\partial U(x,y,z,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})/\partial t$ is always zero, since there is no explicit dependence on $t$.

Comment: You might want to clarify that there is a *possible* explicit dependence on $t$.

Comment: Yes. It is more accurate to say this way. I will edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to use $\partial$, but $d/dt$. In my notes, the lecturer writes $\frac{dU}{dt}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$, using the extended chain rule, and dependence is explicitly given as $U(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I wrote my answer before you make the edition. Well, your extended chain rule should be an extra term $\partial U/\partial t$ but since $U$ does not depend explicitly on time, this term vanishes and the result what you mentioned. Now, if the particle has a time-dependence velocity (at least in one direction, say $x$) you will have $dx/dt = v_{x}(t) \neq 0$, implying $dU/dt \neq 0$. Is this your doubt?

Comment: Yes, thank you! My goal was to simplify $\frac{dV}{dt}$ (see @gandalg61's answer) in a neat manner. If I could "hide" the dependence on $\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z}$ in the time variable $t$, $U(x,y,z,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})\equiv U(x,y,z,t)$, then I could simply use $\frac{dV}{dt}=\nabla U\cdot \dot{r}+ \frac{\partial U}{\partial t}$, where $\nabla$ here is the spatial gradient (over $x,y,z$) and $r=(x,y,z)$.